# Calling a routine when up or down is pressed in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, key-bindings, keystrokes

This code calls a routine when <kbd>enter</kbd> is pressed in a `JTable` (called `gametable`).  It works well, but I would like the same `Action` to be called when moving up or down in the `JTable` without the need for pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>; I can't get it to work.  I tried substituting `VK_ENTER` with `VK_UP`, but I am unable to move up and down the table?

```
KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);

gameTable.getJTable().unregisterKeyboardAction(enter);
gameTable.getJTable().registerKeyboardAction(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
            synchronized (this) {
                gotoGame(gameTable.getSelectedIndex());
            }
        }
    }, enter, JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
```

I can't figure it out. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to separate the steps:

1. First put two `KeyStroke` instances in the `InputMap` so they target the same `actionMapKey`:

   ```
   KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
   KeyStroke up = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0);
   String actionMapKey = "anActionMapKey";
   gameTable.getInputMap().put(enter, actionMapKey);
   gameTable.getInputMap().put(up, actionMapKey);
   ```
2. Then associate that `actionMapKey` with your `Action`:

   ```
   gameTable.getActionMap().put(actionMapKey, new AbstractAction(actionMapKey) {
       ...
   });
   ```

See [*How to Use Actions*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and [*Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details.

I am wary of your use of `synchronized (this)` in this context; you should be constructing your GUI on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: Cheers for this insight.  I've read through your example and read your links on actions and bindings.  I now know that this is the best way forward - just gotta put it all together.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a keylistener to your JTable. Then in your key listener you can check for any button pressed including Enter and take the same action.

I have a program with similar code. Here I just display different values in one textarea if the arrow key choose a different cell, but I think it may give you an idea of how to set it up.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JTable;

public class MyClass {
    static JTable table = new JTable();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        table.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(final java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                tableKeyReleased(evt);
            }
        });
    }

    private static void tableKeyReleased(final java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        final int key = evt.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP || key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN
                || key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            final int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            final int column = table.getSelectedColumn();

            final Object cellValue = table.getValueAt(row, column);

            if (cellValue == null) {
                return;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `KeyListener` is not intrinsically _wrong_, but the question appears to concern key bindings.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question then. Functionally it sounds like what I'm doing with my program. I do have some keybindings too for shortcuts and copy/paste, but that's a different type of functionality.

Comment: `KeyListener` is notorious for "missing" keys.  If the `KeyEvent` is consumed higher in the event handling chain, the `KeyEvent` most likely won't make it to you.  KeyBindings are much more reliable.  IMHO